# how does samsung game luncher detect app as game

Tags: android

I have an huge app that some part of this app is game but I don't want to be detected as game . what should I do ? there is nothing in manifest to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happen if the package name stays default(similar to 'com.example...') in app.json file. Making a change in the default package name could solve your problem.